# C# How to loop through Properties.Settings.Default.Properties changing the values

Tags: c#, programming-languages

I have the following code:

```
foreach (SettingsProperty currentProperty in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
{
    if (Double.TryParse(GenerateValue()), out result))
    {
        currentProperty.DefaultValue = result.ToString();

        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

It gets the new value from a mysql database.  If I add a MessageBox.Show to show the new value it seems to be working fine but it doesn't actually save it.  I assume this is because I am assigning the value to a variable...is there some way to do this?

```
Properties.Settings.Default.IndexOf(currentProperty.name).DefaultValue = result
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This might work:

```
foreach (SettingsProperty  currentProperty in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default[currentProperty.Name] = result.ToString();
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Keep in mind that properties should have scope 'User' in order to be saved.

Comment: I knew there had to be a way to do it.  Thanks a lot for your help.  I did have everything set to User already as well.

Comment: [Alex Azabut] how do I find the scope of the setting?

Comment: I suspect I can use !setting.ReadOnly as user scope, right?

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with your conclusion.  What you are going have to do is get the property by the string value.

```
Properties.Settings.Default[string value] =

    foreach (SettingsProperty currentProperty in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties) 
    {    
    if (Double.TryParse(GenerateValue()), out result))  
       {        

Properties.Settings.Default[ currentProperty.Name ] = result.ToString();
          Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); 
        } 
    }
```

The above is what you actually want.

Comment: My answer would actually compile. *Hint**Hint**Hint*

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to be retrieve the settings and save them back on program startup so that the entire settings file would be editable in appData.
This is what I call when starting the program:

```
            foreach (SettingsProperty currentProperty in Settings.Default.Properties)
            {
                var value = Settings.Default[currentProperty.Name];
                Settings.Default[currentProperty.Name] = value;
                Settings.Default.Save();
            }
```

This seems to work regardless of the type of setting.