# Iterate through properties.settings in runtime

Tags: c#, loops, properties

I've created 32 properties.settings type of int32[,]. 
I will use them during runtime-read and write some data and check every settings values with foreach command. i get some problems iterating through properties values.
Here is my code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     foreach (SettingsProperty c in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
     {
         if (c[0,0]==0)     // i can not reach this byte :(
         {
                c[0, 0] = 1;   // :((
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: I can not iterate through values of properties.settings... How can i see every settings first cell? if (c[0,0]==0) command doesn't work..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The value of a `SettingsProperty` is stored in its `DefaultValue` property. Try the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (SettingsProperty c in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
  {
    if (c.DefaultValue[0,0] == 0)
    {
      c.DefaultValue[0, 0] = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

You might also want to simplify the code using Linq:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (SettingsProperty c in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties
                                                .Cast<object>()
                                                .Where(c => ((int[,])((SettingsProperty)c).DefaultValue)[0, 0] == 0))
  {
    c.DefaultValue[0, 0] = 1;
  }
}
```

Or even better in one line of code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Cast<object>()
                                        .Where(c => ((int[,])((SettingsProperty)c).DefaultValue)[0, 0] == 0)
                                        .ToList()
                                        .ForEach(c => ((int[,])((SettingsProperty)c).DefaultValue)[0, 0] = 1);

  // .ToList() is added because .ForEach() is not available on IEnumerable<T>
  // I added .Cast<object>() to convert from IEnumerable to IEnumerable<object>. Then I use the cast to SettingsProperty so you can use the DefaultValue.
}
```

Finally, this question might be helpful:
[C# How to loop through Properties.Settings.Default.Properties changing the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872994/c-sharp-how-to-loop-through-properties-settings-default-properties-changing-the)

Comment: Moslem, thank you so much for your reply. When i write your offers to my code page, it says that: "System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyCollection" does not contain a definition for "where" and no extension method "where"... Do i make a mistake? Thank you so much...

Comment: My bad. `SettingsPropertyCollection` derives from `IEnumerable` not from `IEnumerable<SettingsProperty>`. I will edit my post shortly to include the hack for that.

Comment: Why it gives error all the time? It says:" Can not apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object' ". Thanks...

Comment: Because the cast must be to `int[,]` not to `int`. Also try to understand the code instead of just copy/pasting. The last error is very trivial and you should have fixed it your self. (Try now with updated code)

Comment: Moslem, thank you so much for your great help. It also let me to learn Linq issue... Take care...

Comment: If the answer is helpeful then please upvote and accept it.

Comment: Moslem, i tried so hard but could not succeed to make your first offer work. It always says me the same thing: " Can not apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'  "

Comment: It does not appear that DefaultValue stores the current value.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the other solution will run, but is incorrect.  You can confirm this by comparing:

`Properties.Settings.Default.Properties[c.name].DefaultValue` and `Properties.Settings.Default[c.name]`, and find that they are different if the property has been assigned a new value -- even if it's been saved.

`DefaultValue` does not store the current value; only the default value in the global scope

To get the actual value, you have to iterate over `Properties.Settings.Default.PropertyValues`.  Like so:

```
foreach(SettingsPropertyValue value in Properties.Settings.Default.PropertyValues )
{
  if (value.PropertyValue[0,0] == 0)
  {
    value.PropertyValue[0, 0] = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Btw, `value.Name` inside the iterator will get you the property name.